# Loop return false

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

My array consist of the below values that gather from XML:

```
beginbegin,endend,-,-,-,begin,end,-,-,-,begin,end,-,-,-,-,begin,-,end,-,-,-,-,begin,-,-,end,-,-,beginbegin,-,continuecontinue,
```

To check whether it has "beginbegin":

```
if(beamStatusArray[a]=="beginbegin") {}
```

It return `false` instead of true, doesn't happen to `begin` or `end`, why it doesn't work when it has a repeat words?

Comment: James, what is your native language?  It's kind of hard to understand. Could you try asking your question in that language, putting it into translate.google.com and re-posting?

Comment: Some would say that cars would behave differently (as a machine) whether a girl is in it or not, but (in theory) it makes no difference. I highly doubt that double words would be found differently than single words in an array in Action Script (considering an exact match). We need more code...

Comment: Mate, what is it exactly you are trying to do? It is abs. not clear to be honest. Could you pass on your code here? It could help.

Comment: Cpfohl, if you don't understand my post, I'm not sure if you are a programmer at all.

Answer (score 1):

where do you get your **`a`** from?
and btw there's an easier way to check if there's a value in an array:

```
var arr:Array = new Array('beginbegin', 'endend', '-', '-', '-', 'begin', 'end', '-', '-', '-', 'begin', 'end', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'begin', '-', 'end', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'begin', '-', '-', 'end', '-', '-', 'beginbegin', '-', 'continuecontinue');
trace(arr.indexOf('beginbegin') != -1);
```

Comment: yes, I could get beginbegin = true on new project. When using existing code, it return false, as for "begin", it return true, could it be SDK array has a bug?

Comment: @ james - a bug in sdk `Array.indexOf()` seems impossible. Could you please paste existing code that returns `false`? imho (if you use `indexOf()` in your code) you get `true` for 'begin' and `false` for 'beginbegin' because you check `arr.indexOf('beginbegin') > 0` while if you get the match at the first element, it returns 0